# Как сделать проверку элементов массива построчно для поиска в каждой строке своего min числа?

Tags: pascal

Есть задача:

В прямоугольной матрице в каждой строке поменять местами первый элемент строки и элемент, содержащий минимальное число в строке.

Заполнение и вывод матрицы я сделала. Потом создала еще один одномерный массив, в который переписала строки.

Теперь хочу сравнить элементы строк между собой. Но что-то опять не в ту степь зашла. Как нужно сделать так, чтобы каждая строка рассматривалась отдельно? У меня, кажется, ищется минимальное значение во всей матрице...

И если даже найду минимальное значение в каждой строке, то как поменять первый элемент с минимальным в строке? Наверное, нужна еще какая-то переменная...

```
function min_v_strokah:integer;
   var i,j : integer;         {peremennie dlya cikla}
       min : integer;         {dlya poiska minimalnogo znacheniya}

   begin
      writeln;

      for i:=1 to a1 do
      begin
         for j:=1 to b1 do
         begin
            sravnenie[j]:=matr[i,j];  {perepisivaem stroki v massiv sravnenie[j]}

            if sravnenie[j] > matr[i,j] then
               begin
                  matr[i,j] := min;

               end;
         end;
            writeln;writeln;
      end;

   end;
```

Comment: Этот код никогда не выполнится:

    begin
      matr[i,j] := min;
    end;

Из-за присвоения `sravnenie[j]:=matr[i,j];` условие `sravnenie[j] > matr[i,j]` всегда будет ложным.

Comment: И зачем, как в [одном из предыдущих вопросов](http://hashcode.ru/questions/71800), переписывать элементы в отдельный массив?

Comment: :) Почему-то мне так было понятнее:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i := 1 to a1 do
begin
  minj := 1;
  for j := 2 to b1 do
    if matr[i, j] < matr[i, minj] then
      minj := j;
  tmp := matr[i, 1]; {tmp - переменная для обмена}
  matr[i, 1] := matr[i, minj];
  matr[i, minj] := tmp;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы поменять 1-й с минимальным, нужно создать переменную, которая еще и будет хранить индекс минимального элемента. Не забудь проверку, потому что 1-й элемент и сам может быть минимальным!

```
 element:integer;
 for i:=1 to a1 do
      begin
      min:=0;//если все ч-а положительные
      index:=0;
         for j:=1 to b1 do
         begin
            if matr[i,j]>min then min:=matr[i,j];
            index:=j;
         end;
      element:=matr[i,1];
      matr[i,1]:=min;
      matr[i,index]:=element;
 end;
 end;
```

Comment: вот этот код, наверное, нужно в "begin-end" обернуть

     min:=matr[i,j];
            index:=j;

в `if` условие неправильное - ищет максимум.